# Edit Text and put it to List View

Tags: android

I'm kinda new to Android Studio so I will be grateful if you can help me with my question. How can I enter some text and add it to a `ListView` with the use of a `Bundle`?

For example, say I enter a name in the `EditText` component in the MainActivty, and then when I press the OK button, it will be seen in to another Activity in a List View.

I've been using `Bundle`s to transfer text to another `Activity` but I can't figure out how to transfer text to `ListView`.

Comment: I don't think you use `Bundle`s for transferring text to a `ListView`.

Comment: but I need to transfer the EditText to another class like what bundle can do

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is display strings in your list items, you can do it fairly simply, otherwise you will have to make a custom adapter. For the former, this is what you will want to do

- Create an `ArrayList<String>` where you will store your values that are entered from the `EditText`.
- Create an `ArrayAdapter<String>` that will serve to connect the `ArrayList` to the `ListView`.

Your final code will look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listView;
    List<String> strings;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
         setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

         listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);

         strings = new ArrayList<String>();
         strings.add("list item 1");
         strings.add("list item 2");

         arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, 
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 strings);

         listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    }
}
```

Then in the onClick of the "OK" button simply add the string from the EditText to the arrayList, and notify the listView that it should be updated be calling this:

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `Bundle`s for what you want to achieve. Here's how I do it...

First you need to set up your list. I would use global variables:

```
ListView listView;
EditText editText;
ArrayList<String> strings;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

Now, in `onCreate()` , you can do...

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edittext );
strings = new ArrayList<>();
adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You will need to set the `OnClickListener` for your `Button`. I would do this in `onCreate()` too:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
button .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Here we get the text from the EditText component
        String text = editText.getText().toString();

        // Now add it to the list
        strings.add(text);

        // And finally, update the list
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: all the codes are in the same Class? because my button is in another class

Comment: @TaengooKim Correct me if I'm wrong. In Activity 1, you have the EditText and Button, and when you click the Button, the text from the EditText is added to the list. The list is in Activity 2. Is this what you are asking?